# Нахождение среди четных положительных чисел одномерного массива минимального и максимального значения, а так же их номера. Java

Tags: java, массивы, java-8

Пытался задать условие, но что-то не получается. Выдает то и дело отрицательный элемент массива, хотя вроде бы прописал, что Y[i]>0.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class KT3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n, b, s=0, c=0, sr;
System.out.println("Введите кол-во элементов массива (не более 50-ти):");
n=in.nextInt();
int Y[] = new int[n];
System.out.println("Введите элементы массива:");
for(int i=0; i<Y.length; i++) {
         Y[i] = in.nextInt(); // ввод элементов
  }
int mini=0, min=Y[0], maxi=0, max=Y[0];
    for(int i=0; i<Y.length; i++){
        if(Y[i]>0 && Y[i]<min){
            mini=i++;
            min=Y[i];
        }
        if(Y[i]>0 && Y[i]>max){
            maxi=i++;
            max=Y[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" Максимальное значение положительного элемента " +max + " его номер " +maxi + "\n Минимальное значение положительного элемента" +min +" его номер" +mini );
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int mini=0, min=Y[0], maxi=0, max=Y[0];
```

Ecли первый элемент отрицательный, то он так и останется записанным в минимальные.

Можно сделать `min=Integer.MAX_VALUE`